# Lua pattern to replace any word,character, digit or symbol followed by a paticular string

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I want to replace any word, character, digit or symbol (except `; , .`) followed by the string `"some-word\"` in Lua. More like a '*' option in regex. Is there any thing similar to '*' in Lua?

**Example:**

`some-word\\test`  -> `some-word\\###`

`some-word\\b*ax#@$6;`  -> `some-word\\###;`

`some-word\\?foo,>`  -> `some-word\\###,`

The code I'm using:

```
d = "some-word" 
p = (tostring(d).."\\[.%c%w%p^%;^%,^%.]+") 
c = "###" 
s = "testing some-word\\test-2 later some-word\\&^*; some-word\\set_34$ " 
print(p) 
res = (string.gsub(s,p,c)) print(res)
```

Comment: This is the code I am using as of now, but it will replace all symbols, how to exclusively say don't replace ; or , or .

`d = "some-word"
p = (tostring(d).."\\[.%c%w%p^%;^%,^%.]+")
c = "###"
s = "testing some-word\\test-2 later some-word\\&^*; some-word\\set_34$ "
print(p)
res = (string.gsub(s,p,c))
print(res)`

Comment: Please move your comment to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(some%-word)\[^;,.%s]*` works, note that:

- `-` is a magic character in Lua patterns, it needs to be escaped.
- `some%-word` is surrounded by `()`, so that it's captured with `%1`.
- In character class, `^` is used in the beginning to indicate
  complement of the following.

Test:

```
d = "some%-word" 
p = "(" .. d .. ")" .. "\\[^;,.%s]*"
c = "%1###" 
s = "testing some-word\\test-2 later some-word\\&^*; some-word\\set_34$ " 
print(p) 
res = string.gsub(s,p,c)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
(some%-word)\[^;,.%s]*
testing some-word### later some-word###; some-word###
```

Comment: And what if i want the entire some-word\\<text>  to be replaced by ##\\##?
Like this

some-word\\test ->  ##\\##

Comment: @nmuliker Change `c` to `"##\\##" `